# Print the last field using 'cut'

Tags: shell, unix, field, cut

Let's say I've the following data:

```
ae722d1d94dcd3b161af166936:!]z@.:123
09338b2b29919e6c0daefbcce0361335:21f2e48d86f28ab7cd5c9c95:123
$H$92Gh.gRJwECLPzkjACPihoLg/:123
c6f1cb5f1feeece60f9a8e067e0:v4Zz'Cj5_Ze{J+iRW{2z,<~:123
202cb962a75b964b07152d234b70:123
40bd0015630c35165329ea5ecbdbbeef:123
```

(Invaild hashes, for explaining purpose only)

I want to use the `cut` tool in printing the last field only.

```
123
123
123
123
123
123
```

- I don't want to use `rev` command.
- I want nothing other than **cut**, I know how to do it in `sed`, `awk`.

`--complement` flag might help!

Comment: No, I get to study Biochemistry for homework.

Comment: Why can you only use `cut`? Maybe there's a better way to solve this.

Comment: There's definitely better ways to solve this. Heck, even *bash itself* could solve it better.

Comment: @all: I know there are +1M ways to do this. But `cut` is the one needed here.

Comment: How do I create a file using `ls`?  How do I execute a command on a remote machine using only `dd`?  How do I [do action X] using [tool not designed for action X]?  These are all foolish questions.  Use the right tool for the job.  For this job, `cut` is the wrong tool.

Comment: @William Pursell: Thanks for being so helpful!

Answer (score 4):

For that specific data you can:

```
cut -f2- -d: file | cut -f2 -d:
```

If you might have three colons:

```
cut -f2- -d: file | cut -f2- -d: | cut -f2 -d:
```

You can keep adding more `cut`s as needed.

The trick is that `cut` does nothing to a record that doesn't have the delimiter so you can use successive `cut`s to chop off the first field while leaving the last fields that you've already found alone.

Comment: Thanks! I actually like the idea of multiple `cut`s.

Answer (score 4):

i saw this on another place when I was looking for this answer.

rev, cut (on delimiter) -f 1, rev

move the last field forward, cut it, and move it back

i thought that was kinda slick